# Why the `$remote_addr` variable in nginx shows differently in the nginx logs in comparison with what I send in the reverse proxy header `X-Real-IP`?

Tags: nginx, logging, proxypass, request-headers

Usually the access log shows an internal IP address, but in the `X-Real-IP` header shows the external IP address. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

`$remote_addr` gives the IP address of the reverse proxy server, `X-Real-IP` is the default header which Nginx uses to pass the original client IP to servers running behind the reverse proxy.

Without some way of passing the original IP then all your traffic would appear to originate from your reverse proxy

Comment: What would be the best way to pass the original client IP to the `location` of the reverse proxy? I tried `map` and setting a variable, but it does not work.